# How to get the inner object value dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects like this

```
var row = {
    destination: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test'
    },
    name: 'test2',
    source: 'source2'
};
var obj = [{'index': 'name'}, {'index': 'source'}, {'index': 'destination.name'}];
```

Now looping on obj I can get values of row but not for the destination.name

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
    console.log(row[obj.index]);
}
```

Output

```
test2
source2
undefined
```

Comment: `row[obj.index]` has syntax error.

Comment: @Praveen: No, it's valid syntax. `obj.index` is evaluated first and then *that* value is used as property name. *edit:* ah yeah, the `i` is missing. But I guess it's just a typo here, otherwise the OP would not get that output.

Comment: @Praveen: Not *syntax*, but definitely an error. Should be `row[obj[i].index]` I believe.

Comment: @FelixKling oops.  sorry my bad, missing `i` value within that.

Comment: How to determine at runtime that the object has some inner level object???

Comment: @coure2011 what output are you expecting?

Comment: Well, if you look at the accepted answer in the linked question, the function returns `undefined` if the property doesn't exist.

Comment: @Praveen I want the output "test" instead of undefined

Comment: @coure2011 The problem is `'destination.name'` is considering as a whole string.  Hence it is not considering it. So you need to again check into it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your question

```
var row = {
  destination: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test'
  },
  name: 'test2',
  source: 'source2'
};
var obj = [
 {'index': 'name'}, 
 {'index': 'source'}, 
 {'index': {'destination':'name'}}
];

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
  if(typeof(obj[i].index) == 'object'){
    var x = obj[i].index;
    var key = Object.keys(x)[0];
    var innerkey = obj[i].index[key];
    console.log(row[key][innerkey]);
  } else {
    console.log(row[obj[i].index]);
  }
}
```